# Access the Search Widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

At the moment I try to Access the Search Widget.

I don’t know how I can implement a key listener.
How I can implement the method?

Is anyone out there who can give me a tip or a tutorial??

Here is my code.

**menü.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings_option_item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:title="Einstellungen"
    android:showAsAction="never">    </item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/aktualiesieren"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
    android:title="Aktualiesieren"
    android:showAsAction="always"        >

</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/suche"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:title="Suche"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
     android:title="Search"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
     android:showAsAction="always"
     android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

**settings.java**

```
package com.de.xx.einstellungen;


import com.de.xx.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Einstellungen extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.einstellungen);
    }

}
```

**main.java**

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

thank you